# How to synchronize between differently structured directories using rsync (or other program)

Tags: sync, rsync, repository

Does anyone of you know how to perform the following task: 
Suppose you have two directory trees, which I will call source and target. They may have a very different structure, but could contain many duplicate files.

An example would be a structured collection of photographs on one hand (the destination), and just a tmp directory in which you unload everything from your camera on the other (the source).

Maybe some of these files are already in the structured directory tree. I would like to rsync from the source to the target, such that only the files from the source that are not in the destination *at any location* are copied.

Comment: sounds like you want to compare the contents of two directories recursively. try md5deep, perhaps with a little sorting and a diff.

Comment: Do you want to simply remove duplicates? Because otherwise, where do you want to put the non-dupes that aren't sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Try [fdupes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes):

> fdupes is a program written by Adrian Lopez to scan directories for
>   duplicate files, with options to list, delete or replace the files
>   with hardlinks pointing to the duplicate. It first compares file sizes
>   and MD5 signatures, and then performs a byte-by-byte check for
>   verification.

This wikipedia entry also lists similar programs.

Comment: What is fdupes?  What does it do?  Why does it work so well or not so well?  Please refrain from just adding links, but rather add to it, by adding a description of what it does and why it works.  Sometimes it's even good to give instructions on how to use it.

Comment: @KronoS I haven't used fdupes enough to compare it to other similar programs, but a dupe-finding program seems to be what might be needed here, and this page lists many such programs.

Answer (score 0):

Since your example describes photos; 
Adobe Lightroom does exactly that. It can import pictures into its directory structure while ignoring duplicates.
If you want this function for other types of documents you need another solution though.

Comment: Thanks Mattias. I was looking more for something (lightweight) to operate on existing directory structures though